# find in container of objects of pure virtual classes

Tags: c++, pure-virtual

To achieve container of **non-overlapping intervals** I defined the following:

```
set<unique_ptr<interval>> db;
```

To ensure non-overlapping property have defined:

```
bool operator<(const unique_ptr<interval>& lhs, 
               const unique_ptr<interval>& rhs);
```

The `interval` class has 2 fields: `start`, `last` and so I can determine if some `int` falls in the range of certain `interval` instance.

Now I have an `int n` which I want to search in in the set to find which interval contains it.

I thought on creating `unique_ptr<interval> dummy_interval` with both `first=last=n` and searching call `db.find(dummy_interval)` but the problem is that class `interval` is pure virtual and so I can't create any instance of it.

How can I overcome that?

Comment: derive a "dummy-interval" class and use this one. Or maybe rethink your design to not need one.

Comment: what you mean by cannot create any instance. Can you inherit the interval class or not?

Comment: @Hayt
I could derive the class but I feel it's overkill. Rethink the design? I would be happy to hear suggestions

Comment: redesigning would need the information on why it is that way in the first place and this would get too broad. The alternative would be to not make the base class abstract but it feels for me a subclass where first=last would be the easiest solution.

Comment: The problem with your approach is the items are the keys themselves, so searching for a key means you need an item, which you cannot do. I suggest a refactor, where keys and values are separate, and then your container would be a `map` or `unordered_map`, and you can search easily by key. These also provide logarithmic and amortized constant time access, respectively, so you don't lose anything but moving away from a `set`

Comment: @AndyG I thought on using `unordered_map` but was discouraged due to the fact that I will have redundant information. the range will be specified in the key and also in the value which is the handler

Answer (score 1):

Since you have non-overlapping intervals, you can use [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) with a custom comparator:

```
template <typename It>
It find_interval(It first, It last, int value) {
    // See explanation below.
    auto it = std::lower_bound(first, last, value, 
                               [](const std::unique_ptr<interval>& i1, int value) {
                                   return i1->start < value;
                               });
    if (it != last && (*it)->start == value) {
        return it;
    }
    --it;
    // Change this to: (*it)->end > value ? it : last
    // ...if the upper bound of the interval are not included.
    return (*it)->end < value ? last : it;
}
```

`std::lower_bound` will find the first interval that is *not less* (i.e. *greater or equal*) than value. Since we are comparing with the start, we have two case:

- The value is the start of the interval, in which case the interval itself will be returned (first`if`);
- The value is not the start of the interval, in which case the **next** interval will be returned, so we need to decrement `it` (`--it`).

Since we are only checking the start in `std::lower_bound`, we need to check the end before returning.

`std::lower_bound` has a logarithmic complexity, and the above call is valid because the range `[first, last)` is **ordered** with respect to the comparator we provide (the lambda) - I am assuming `db` is sorted according to the start of intervals.

See http://rextester.com/FBHYH63411 for a full implementation.

**Side note:** If you are not inserting/removing intervals often, you may be better off using a sorted `std::vector`.

---

**Edit:** Old answer -
You probably cannot use `std::set::find` to find your interval because the comparator you are using in `db` compares two `interval`, not an `interval` and an `int`, and `std::set::find` uses this comparator (even with a "dummy" interval, you would need a valid relation, which may be hard to obtain).

Either you need to change the structure and use, e.g., an [Interval Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) to keep logarithmic complexity, or you use the non-"specialized" [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) with linear complexity:

```
std::find(db.begin(), db.end(), [n](const std::unique_ptr<interval> &it) {
    return it->start < n && n < it->end;
});
```

Comment: using linear algorithm is not an option. I'm trying to implement interval tree and I face this problem

Comment: @HannaKhalil If you are implementing an interval tree and storing `interval` in the tree, you probably have an issue somewhere. An interval tree represents a collection of intervals but its nodes are not interval themselves, which makes queries in logarithmic complexity possible.

Comment: could you explain what you mean? I'm implementing interval trees by having `std::set<interval>`

Comment: @HannaKhalil You cannot implement interval tree with a single `std::set<interval>` because with `std::set` you have a relation on `interval` which will be based only on start or end (which is not what you want - except if none of the interval are overlapping). An interval tree is a custom structure where each node represent a time point, not an interval, and contains multiple intervals.

Comment: I do want non overlapping intervals

Comment: @HannaKhalil Add this to your question. In this case you can use `std::set<interval>` (but you cannot call it an interval tree). With this, you could probably use a dummy interval class with `std::set::lower_bound` or `std::set::upper_bound`.

Comment: @HannaKhalil See updated answer using `std::lower_bound` with a custom comparator (no need for a dummy interval actually).